How to Trigger the follow-up SMS message in Salesforce Marketing Cloud
Is there a way to trigger the follow-up sms message using Salesforce Marketing Cloud MobileConnect 2-way short code for the French market(In Journey Builder)?
These are the detailed context.

System Environment : Automotive Cloud and Marketing Cloud are integrated.

Requirement



Send the first service satisfaction survey message.

Send condition : 10 min after the phone conversation.(Using Salesforce Data Event Entry Source)
Message content: "On a scale of 0 to 10, how satisfied were you with your telephone conversation with the agent? Enter your score by replying directly to this text message."


Customer replies with a score between 0-10 to the first service satisfaction survey message.

If the score is between 0-4, send a follow-up message right after MC got the answer for the first message.

Message content: "Which area needs improvement? 1. Friendliness 2. Accuracy."


Customer replies to the second message.

Create a survey message report.
-Content : Number of surveys requested/delivered (or bounced)/answered by record type/by dealer/by period/by region.


Thank You

If you configure your first outbound send to use a next keyword, then you would have another text response message configured in mobile connect for the next keyword defined earlier. You would leverage ampscript to parse the response and the next keyword functionality to string messages and responses togther.
You can use ampscript to write responses to a DE or leverage the _smsmessagetracking dataview
